# retrieve theme custom settings

Tags: customization, options, theme-customizer

I have modified twentythirteen template adding custom settings for my theme.
All settings appear in theme customization section and I am able to save them.

I am using WP 3.6.

How to retrieve those custom settings in my theme file?

Comment: How did you add your custom settings?

Comment: Could you please start following up on the comments and answers to your older questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default the settings of Twenty Thirteen are saved in DB in the `wp_options` table, with the option_name `theme_mods_twentythirteen`. You can get them with: `get_option('theme_mods_twentythirteen')`.

Also you must know that from version 3.4 WordPress uses a [Customize Manager](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager).

Comment: @renathy, Is this what you needed?